# How to programatically download a video?

Tags: node.js, video, download, mp4, 3gp

I'm trying to programmatically download a video file from a web-server through a link.

If you'd click that link through a web-browser it would just prompt you to download the video and to provide a name for the file and then download the video properly.

I have some nodejs code that just makes an HTTP request to that link and successfully gets raw data from it and saves it to a default file `video.mp4`

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

https.get('https://url.tocdn.com/myvideoid', (resp) => {
let data = '';

// A chunk of data has been recieved.
resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
});

// The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
resp.on('end', () => {
    fs.writeFile('./video.mp4', data, (err) => console.log(err))
});

}).on("error", (err) => {
console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

The problem is that when I try to play that file through Windows Media Player, for example, it just shows an error regarding the file format. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: if you compare the downloaded file to the same one manually downloaded, are they the same length (and if the same length does a byte-by-byte comparison show any differences in content), also I assume the source is also mp4?

Comment: I don't think they're the same (haven't tried), but I'll check it and edit my post about it!

Comment: might help work out if node isn't downloading everything, or doing something weird (I usually force resp.setEncoding('utf8') to make sure I get what I think I'm getting for instance)

Comment: Sorry, Christmas and new year went over this project. I've found out that I'm trying to read a `application/octet-stream` and I'm apending that to a string which maybe is the cause that I'm getting almost the double amount of bytes that I'm supposed to read...

Comment: Yes that is definitely it. In the `resp.on('data')` callback I'm adding the `length` of the `chunk` to an external accumulator variable and the total amount of bytes match. So I'm corrupting the incoming data by using `string`s

Comment: Solved it, that was it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Don't use `string` if you're pretending to store bytes,

#### or `application/octet-stream` in my case (which is the same)

From the given snippet change:

```
resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data = Buffer.concat([data, Buffer.from(chunk)]);
});
```

And make sure to initialize `data` as follows:
`let data = Buffer.from([]);`